# PHP calculation isn't correct

Tags: php

I am beginner at PHP and I want to create a program which converts decimal numbers to hexadecimal numbers. (In fact I want to convert my color decimal value to hexadecimal value) However, It doesn't work properly. For example when I press convert button with this parameters: red=98 blue=123 green=54
It generates this result:

`Red :
Green :
Blue : B`

I don't understand what wrong is.

This is my source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert Decimal Number to Hexadecimal Number</title>
<form method="POST" action="index.php" >
    Red  :  <input type="text" name="red" /> <br />
    Green:  <input name="green" type="text" /> <br />
    Blue :  <input name="blue" type="text" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate!" /> <br />
</form>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $completely="";
    if ($_POST['red']==""){
        exit();
    }
    function subcalculate($valuetoconvert){
        if ($valuetoconvert>9){
            switch ($valuetoconvert){
                case 10:
                    $valuetoconvert=A;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    $valuetoconvert=B;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    $valuetoconvert=C;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    $valuetoconvert=D;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    $valuetoconvert=E;
                    break;
                case 15:
                    $valuetoconvert=F;
                    break;
            }
            return $valuetoconvert;
        }
    }
    function dectohexcal($color,$colorname){
        $bir=subcalculate(($color-($color%16))/16);
        $iki=subcalculate($color%16);
        if ($bir==0){
            echo "$colorname :    $iki <br />";
            $completely=$completely+$iki;
        }else{
            echo "$colorname :    $bir$iki <br />";
            $completely=$completely+$bir+$iki;
        }

    }
    dectohexcal($_POST['red'], "Red");
    dectohexcal($_POST['green'], "Green");
    dectohexcal($_POST['blue'], "Blue");
    echo "<br />$completely";
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's a function that converts decimals to hexadecimals: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

Comment: And your problem seems to be that you only return `$valuetoconvert` inside `subcalculate()` when the number is >9, so it doesn't return anything <=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only use the
    dechex() 
function which is available with php4+.

```
<?php
echo "Red: ".dechex($_POST['red']) . "\n";
echo "Green: ". dechex($_POST['green'])."\n";
echo "Blue: ".dechex($_POST['blue']);
?>
```

This should get your work done without the need for re-inventing the wheel.